# EE homework is kicking my behind

Tags: discussion

EE student here, having a hell of a time with some homework. Is this the right place to ask for some help or guidance?

Comment: help yes but you need to show effort

Comment: Probably better at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

If it's about signal processing, sure. As Hilmar suggests in the comments, the [EE site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) might be better for other questions.

Just be sure to put in as much of a solution as you can, and show where you start misunderstanding or not getting it.  We will give advice on homework, we just won't do your homework for you.